# Highligh input default value and replace instead of writing before or after

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with default values for example 0. 
When i click  i would like that 0 to highlight and when someone starts to write value replace the default value instead of writing before or after.

Comment: Yeah, that's really nice functionality, and you were very friendly when you told us about this feature. Did you have a programming specific question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLInputElement.select()` to select an inputs content. Also good to use `focus()` to focus it as well, [as sometimes it doesn't.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

```
const field = document.getElementById('yourId')

field.addEventListener('click', () => {
    field.select()
})
```